# Intercept a Print Job to add extra data

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible in Windows to intercept a Print Job parse the contents and add some extra data to the Print job?

Comment: Yes, you would write a device driver. Would you care to give any further insight as to your level of experience or what sort of extra data you want to add?

Comment: I haven't done anything like this before. What I am trying to do is add a string to the receipt that gets printed from different 3rd systems.

Comment: Is this for a receipt printer?

Comment: It could be. I am trying to come up with a generic solution. One other thing that I forgot to mention was I might have to parse the text getting printed that will allow me to decide what the text needs to be..

Comment: This is why I asked, because for a "generic desktop laser/inkjet printer" it would be printing postscript from the windows drivers. Those are different from the kinds of things printed by receipt printers (which are often serial streams of data and proprietarily formatted). I don't think you're going to be able to create a one size fits all printer driver for this, you're going to have to tailor it to each printer system you're going to work with. Additionally, there is a specific thing about creating "generic" systems. You have to write one or two and make sure where they overlap.

Comment: So what you need to do is to write the first one. Then write the second one. Then figure out how and where they overlap. There is no magic to this. Time to take a trip down the rabbit hole and see how far down it goes.

Comment: Can you point me to some resources to write the first one? Thanks for your help..

Comment: Yes probably you are right as you can see I haven't done driver development at all. I have started looking at the WDK and will try to ask some more intelligent questions..

Comment: So you need to start with the type of printer you're going to be working with initially. That's step 1. Step 2 is finding out what software SDK they have available for this sort of thing. Step 3 is finding other printers you're likely to work with in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[The AddJob function adds a print job to the list of print jobs that can be scheduled by the print spooler. The function retrieves the name of the file you can use to store the job.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)