# Custom Print Driver: Editing Print File Before It Is Sent To Printer

Tags: .net, windows, printing

I would like to develop an application that would append a custom header and footer to files(reports from a third party application) before they are printed. The information in the header and footer would be text and a bar code. For the driver development It seems like the best tools available are Windows Driver Kit 7, RedMon, Ghostscript and PostScript.

Most of my experience comes from developing Windows Form applications, database development and Java applications. So I feel lost at were to begin this type of development.  I am looking for general advice and a direction to help me get started on this project.

I found these links useful: 
[Intercept a Print Job to add extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554876/intercept-a-print-job-to-add-extra-data)

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/postscript-driver.html

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm